# solr boost query with separate sort

Tags: sorting, boost, solr, solr-query-syntax

I want to demote all documents that have inv=0(possible values from 0 to 1000) to the end of the result set. i have got other sorting options like name desc also as part of the query.

For example below are my solr documents

```
Doc1 : name=apple , Inv=2
Doc2 : name=ball , Inv=1
Doc3 : name=cat , Inv=0
Doc4 : name=dog , Inv=0
Doc5 : name=fish , Inv=4
Doc6 : name=Goat , Inv=5
```

I want achieve below sorting ...here, i want to push all documents with inv=0 down to bottom and then apply "name asc" sorting.

```
Doc1
Doc2
Doc5
Doc6
Doc3
Doc4
```

my solr request is like

> bq: "(: AND -inv:"0")^999.0" & defType: "edismax"

here 999 is the rank that i gave to demote results.

this boosting query works fine. it moves all documents with inv=0 down to the bottom.

But when i add &sort=name asc to the solr query, it prioritizes "sort" over bq..i am seeing below results with "name asc".

```
Doc1 : name=apple , Inv=2
Doc2 : name=ball , Inv=1
Doc3 : name=cat , Inv=0
Doc4 : name=dog , Inv=0
Doc5 : name=fish , Inv=4
Doc6 : name=Goat , Inv=5
```

can anyone please help me out. ?

Answer (score 3):

Sort will override the boost.

So, you either move your sort into boost by making that condition map into boost values.

Or you move your boost condition into sort, using **query()** syntax. This was one of the gems from [the Lucene/Solr Revolution 2016 presentation by hoss](https://home.apache.org/~hossman/rev2016/#/36/3) (click start presentation):

```
        qq = Harry
         q = +{!edismax v=$qq}
        qf = title actor writer director  keywords
      sort = query($title_sort,0) desc, title asc
title_sort = {!field f=title v=$qq}
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement this query in dismax format?

Answer (score 1):

Default sorting criteria in Solr is `score desc`, where `score` is a virtual field and it actually represents the document's score.

Once one is passing `&sort=name asc` it will override default sorting.

Possible solution here might be something like this: `&sort=score desc, name asc`. Which literally means: please sort by `score` first and for documents with equal score please make a tie-break by `name` ascending.

It should work as long as you will have equal scores for doc1, doc2, doc5, doc6.

If it is not the case - then check out this [Solr Wiki link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F) for more details how to penalize docs with `inv:0`.