# How to nested sort in solr query?

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax

Assume I have field and value like

```
Field : value
sku : xxx
Seller : true
Name : "Elux"
```

query will be like

```
sku:"xxx"
```

within this result I need to sort the products with Name (Elux) in the top with seller (true) top
and within that I need the products name should be sorted in alphabetical order same goes for seller (false) and Name other than Elux in the bottom. Is this possible with solr?

Comment: `sort=Seller desc, Name`?

Comment: sry my bad, My question i want to sort the products with name (elux) in the top and with in the seller (true) in top and with in that product should in sorted in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same strategy as [shown in this answer by Alexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499826/137650), but you'll have to adapt it to your need. Something like:

```
&sort=query(Name:Elux, 0) desc, query(seller:true, 0) desc, Name asc
```

.. should work. Not sure about the performance from those two `query` calls, though.

Update:

You'll have to use placeholders as Alexandre describes in his answer:

```
sort=query($manu_sort,0) desc, query($seller_sort,0) desc, ManufacturerName asc
&manu_sort=ManufacturerName:Champ
&seller_sort=BestSeller:true
```

Comment: Im getting this erro when i use "&sort=query(Name:Elux, 0) desc"   "Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec 'query(Name:Elux, 0) desc', pos=16"

Comment: You'll probably have to use "" around the query, or use the method described in the linked answer with placeholders. Try it and I'll update the answer if it works or remove it if not.

Comment: How does this query work "query(Name:Elux, 0) desc" can you explain It dosent seems to be working for me. Thanks for your time

Comment: Im getting a error like "sort param could not be parsed as a query,"

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, try to use `"` around the query, or use placeholders as shown in the linked answer by Alexandre.

Comment: Add five example documents in JSON to your question and the expected output and I'll dig further in a couple of hours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195324/discussion-between-pradeep-murugan-and-matslindh).

Comment: Thankyou and final thing how to make this "ManufacturerName:Champ" case insensitive ?

Comment: You add a LowercaseFilter to your processing chain for that field.

Comment: How do I change this query to dismax type?

Comment: The sort query or the general query? `defType=edismax` would change the type of the query itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I need to implement this sort in dismax query format.

Comment: I used this query "q=*:*&sort=query({!dismax v=$manu_sort},0) desc &manu_sort=ManufacturerName:"Service Champ" Im getting error "Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec 'query({!dismax v=$manu_sort},0) desc ', pos=14"

Comment: can you give me a sample query? I dono what you mean by "Try inside manu_sort"

Comment: `manu_sort={!dismax}ManufacturerName:"Service Champ"  or `manu_sort={!dismax v=ManufacturerName:"Service Champ"}`. You should also be able to use `edismax` - the more modern version. dismax is usually used without a field name and with the `qf` parameter instead.