# Solr boost and the sort

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have been researching methods for applying a boost parameter to my solr queries and I have a problem. The issue is that I originally implemented my query with a default sort and now I want to boost a specific property. I have read that I can use something called an elevator, but the discussion was from 4 years ago. It would be a lot of work to change my configurations to elevator. The URL that I am working with is:

`q=("Crystal"~4)(*Crystal*)&start=0&rows=24&fq=department:(eyeglasses)&fq=status:(active)&facet=true&facet.field=gender&facet.field=department&facet.field=color&facet.field=frame_shape&facet.field=frame_material&facet.field=face_shape&facet.limit=-1&indent=on&!type=edismax&bq=name(Sullivan)&sort=has_images+desc%2cseller_rank+asc%2cin_stock+desc%2cbrand_rank+asc%2cname+desc&version=2.2&wt=json`

I am trying to boost `bq=name:(Sullivan)` and sort `sort=has_images+desc%2cseller_rank+asc%2cin_stock+desc%2cbrand_rank+asc%2cname+desc`.

The problem is the sort takes priority and my boost doesn't affect the results. Perhaps someone else has encountered this problem.

Comment: First - what is your actual goal? What do you want the result to be, since you're sorting by several parameters (which excludes score) and using an additional boost (which only affects score). Is it to use the boost as a tie-breaker?

Comment: Also [see the answer by Alexandre here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499826/137650) for another possible workaround.

Comment: Yes, thank you @MatsLindh. I have elected to use ```sort score desc```. I'm trying to avoid creating this elevator configuration early on just because I'm so unfamiliar with it. Do you think it will be easy to add the elevator configuration in the future? Basically, I have one parameter and if that parameter is set THEN I want to boost THEN sort. Otherwise just apply my normal sort. I would like to know your thoughts on this. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Elevation is for lifting certain documents to the top for specific keywords; it's not  for sorting differently depending on specific parameters.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. I am trying my best to understand the solr documentation, but it's taking a little longer than I thought.